# Passing objects from child to parent page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, serialization

I have two web pages, parent and child. On click of add in parent I open popup and where i will enter the details and save. Upon save I would like refresh the data in parent Grid. Following are the approcahes i was thinking

1. Use Session varible on save and use it on parent.
2. Store the values in DB on child and retrive it.
3. Serilize the object in Child and assign that to partent hidden varible on refresh de-serilze on server and bind it to the grid.

I would like to know from the group what is the best way to do this. I was thinking of doing the third approcah?

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 and Jquery for popup window.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to do it this way:

1. OnSave in child page wait for
   server response and
2. if save is successful do
   parent.grid.reload (this is very
   generic but i hope you get the point)
3. if save is not successful you can
   do some nice exception/error
   handling on child page and ask again
   for input etc

Answer (score 1):

Best not to refresh the master. User will not expect that and may loose
some state on the master, for example filter/sorting.

Best use window to window communication with window.opener to directly tell master what detail was edited or inserted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick update to the parent window without reloading it, you can access/modify variables/functions in parent window's scope (provided they are on the same domain) with `window.parent.somevar = 'x'` or `window.parent.someFoo()`. But you would still need to make a server request from one of the windows in order to store it in DB.

Answer (score 0):

In general (not specifically in asp.net) I would just have the popup send a "refresh from DB" signal in one way or another to its parent (with window.parent). 
The advantage of this is that you make sure that the parent gets the actual data that was saved. Otherwise you would need the pop-up to check itself if the save succeeded, and if the object that it wants to send to its parent is actually correct.

Edit: Actually the pop-up should probably check for saving success as another answer says. Still I wouldn't have it do more than call a refresh method on the caller window, unless maybe that refresh is extremely costly.